# AlarmManager and Notification not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I've read several questions regarding this topic, but I still can't figure it out.

I need to show a notification every day at the same time. I'm using AlarmManager. It looks like it is well written, but I won't actually receive any alarm.
SyncAlarmReceiver never calls onReceive().

Here is the code to set the alarm:

```
private static final int ORA_NOTIFICA = 14;   //Hour for the notification
private static final int MINUTO_NOTIFICA = 35;  //Minutes for the notification
private static final int ID_NOTIFICA_SYNC = 33;  //Notification's ID

public static void setSyncAlarm(Context ctx) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, ORA_NOTIFICA);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MINUTO_NOTIFICA);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, getPendingIntentSync(ctx));
    Log.d("NOTIFICA SYNC", "Alarm set at " + ORA_NOTIFICA + ":"
            + MINUTO_NOTIFICA);
}


public static PendingIntent getPendingIntentSync(Context ctx) {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, new Intent(ctx,
            SyncAlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Here is the SyncAlarmReceiver:

```
public class SyncAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("NOTIFICA SYNC", "Alert Ricevuto");
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    NotificationUtils.createNotifSync(context);

    wl.release();
}
```

}

And finally the createNotifSync:

```
public static void creaNotificaSync(Context ctx) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            ctx).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.action_bar_icon)
            .setContentTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.sync_notif_titolo))
            .setContentText(ctx.getString(R.string.sync_notif_testo))
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ctx, ActTestJson.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ctx);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ActTestJson.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(ID_NOTIFICA_SYNC, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Also, the snippet from the Manifest:

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.mypackage.SyncAlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </receiver>
```

EDIT: That's what I found using findstr on the dumbsys alarm

```
adb shell dumpsys alarm | findstr /C:com.mypackage

RTC_WAKEUP #33: Alarm{42bd9470 type 0 com.mypackage} operation=PendingIntent{429d3238: PendingIntentRecord42fe80a0 com.mypackage startService}}

ELAPSED #12: Alarm{42b4fcc8 type 3 com.mypackage} operation=PendingIntent{42914e20: PendingIntentRecord{42a2a198 com.mypackage broadcastIntent}}

com.contram.unicam.controllori +15ms running, 6 wakeups: +15ms 6 wakes 6 alarms: cmp={com.mypackage/com.mypackage.utils.SyncAlarmReceiver}
```

RTC_WAKEUP and ELAPSED are here because I tried using both methods (not really understanding the difference).

EDIT:
I've tried reading the calendar used to set the time, this is what comes out of its toString():

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1386194671008,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,
zone=Europe/Rome,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=11,
WEEK_OF_YEAR=49,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_YEAR=338,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,
DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE=4,SECOND=31,MILLISECOND=8,
ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

Using an online millis-to-time converter, the time parameter converts to Wed Apr 08 2409 06:45:10 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time).

What should I use to set the time?

Comment: Use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to confirm that your alarm is being set and when it is to be invoked next.

Comment: That's a huge mess. Is there a way to filter out only the alarms from my package?

Comment: Search for your package name, using **`fgrep`**, **`grep`**, or the equivalent.

Comment: I've added what I could find to the question.

Comment: I've edited the original question, including what I could read about the calendar object used to set the alarm.

Comment: According to http://www.epochconverter.com/, the milliseconds value is exactly what the rest of the fields say: Wed, 04 Dec 2013 22:04:31 GMT

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with ELAPSED_TIME in:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, getPendingIntentSync(ctx));
```

Changed to RTC, it worked.